# Hamming weight ( number of 1 in a number) mixing C with assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, hammingweight

I'm trying to count how many number 1, are in the numbers of an array.

First I have a code in C lenguaje(work ok):

```
int popcount2(int* array, int len){
    int i;
    unsigned x;
    int result=0;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        x = array[i];
        do{
           result+= x & 0x1;
           x>>= 1;
       } while(x);
    }
return result;
}
```

Now I need to translate the do-while loop into Assembly using 3-6 lines of code. I have write some code but the result is not correct.( I'm new in the assembly world )

```
int popcount3(int* array, int len){
int  i;
unsigned x;
int result=0;   
for (i=0; i<len; i++){
    x = array[i];
    asm(
    "ini3:               \n"
        "adc $0,%[r]     \n"
        "shr %[x]        \n"
        "jnz ini3        \n"

        : [r]"+r" (result)
        : [x] "r" (x)       );
  }
}
```

I'm using GCC ( on linux) with an Intel processor.

Comment: Your code is wrong for at least 2 reasons: 1) it doesn't initalize the carry flag, so it may be set and 2) the last bit you shift out isn't accounted for.

Comment: Related: [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) shows a branchless bithack implementation which is quite nice and easy to implement on x86.  If hardware `popcnt` or SSSE3 `pshufb` aren't available, it or a table lookup are probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest think you can do is using built in `popcount` function as [suggested by Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27050677/1149736), but since you need to write it in assembly, this worked for me:

```
asm (
"start:                  \n"
        "and %0, %1      \n"
        "jz end          \n"
        "shr $0, %1      \n"
        "jnc start       \n"
        "inc %1          \n"
        "jmp start       \n"
"end:                    \n"
        : "+g" (result),
          "+r" (x)
        :
        : "cc"
);
```

At first two lines you just check the contents of `x` (and go to end if it's zero `Jump Zero`). Than you shift `x` one bit to right and:

> At the end of the shift operation, the [`CF` flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register#Flags) contains the last bit shifted out of the destinationoperand. [*](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf)

If there's no `CF` set, just go to start (`Jump Not Carry`) else increment result and then go to start.

And the beautiful think about assembly is that you can do things in so many ways...

```
asm (
"start:                  \n"
        "shr $1, %1      \n"
        "jnc loop_cond   \n"
        "inc %0          \n"
        "and %1, %1      \n"
"loop_cond:              \n"
        "jnz start       \n"

        : "+g" (result),
          "+r" (x)
        :
        : "cc"
);
```

Here you again use `SHift Right` instruction, if no `CF` is present just go to loop condition.

Otherwise again increment result and call binary `AND` (`INC` *does* modify `ZF`).

---

#### Using `LOOP` and `ECX`

*I was curious how to do this in 3 instruction (I figured your teacher wouldn't give you bottom limit of 3 if it wasn't possible) and* I realized x86 also has [`LOOP` instruction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Loop_Instructions):

> Each time the LOOP instruction is executed, the count register is decremented, then checked for 0. If the count is 0, the loop is terminated and program execution continues with the instruction following the LOOP instruction. If the count is not zero, a near jump is performed to the destination (target) operand, which is presumably the instruction at the beginning of the loop. [*](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf)

And you can add input argument using [GCCs input constrain](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints):

> `c` - The `c` register.

```
asm (
"start:              \n"
    "shr $1, %1      \n"
    "adc $0, %0      \n"
    "loop start      \n"

    : "+g" (result)
    : "r" (x),
      "c" (8)             // Assuming 8b type (char)
);
```

Just to make sure it compiles to proper assembly:

```
0x000000000040051f <+25>:   mov    $0x8,%ecx
0x0000000000400524 <+30>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000400527 <+33>:   shr    %edx
0x0000000000400529 <+35>:   adc    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040052c <+38>:   loop   0x400527 <main+33>
```

*I think the first one should have a bit better performance, especially if there's just 1 bit set, this approach always does `k*8` iterations*.

---

#### SSE4 and single instruction

I know you have to use a loop, but just for fun... With [SSE4 extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) you could do this by just one instruction `POPCNT`:

> This instruction calculates of number of bits set to 1 in the second operand (source) and returns the count in the first operand (a destination register). [*](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf)

I *think* (I have a quite old CPU on my notebook, so I can't test this for you) you should be able to do this with just one simple instruction:

```
asm (   
    "POPCNT %1, %0   \n"
    : "=r" (result)
    : "mr" (x)
    : "cc"                                                                                                                                       
);
```

*(If you try this and you do have SSE4 extension, please let me know if it works)*

---

#### Performance

I've measured times required to do 100,000,000 popcounts comparing my first and second methods with [David Wohlferd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053187/1149736). <sup>[[Raw data]](http://pastebin.com/aG3TpTrX)</sup>

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
|              | 0x00000000 | 0x80000001 | 0xffffffff |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1st solution |  0.543     |  5.040     |  3.833     |
| LOOP         | 11.530     | 11.523     | 11.523     |
| Davids       |  0.750     |  4.893     |  4.890     |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

*If anyone can compare these 3 with SSE4's `POPCNT` instruction I'd be glad.*

Comment: In both of these examples, you are declaring x as an input, but you are changing its value.  Very bad idea.  Only outputs can (safely) be changed.  Maybe something more like: `"+g" (result), "=r" (junk) : "1" (x)`.  Also (speaking for myself), I find using symbolic names makes the code easier to read (`inc %[result]` instead of `inc %2`.  And what's with using %2?  Parameters are zero based, so there is no %2?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thanks for notes, I didn't know that about the output/input.... And the `%2` was typo when rewriting answer from "working version" (I was on my way to bed when I've saw the question and got interested). And indeed it's easier to work with symbolic names.

Comment: You don't need the [`loop` instruction.  It's slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  You can do it with 3 insns inside the loop this way:  With CF cleared on loop entry (e.g. from xor-zeroing result), `.l: adc $0, %[res]` ; `shr $1, %[x]` ; `jnz .l`;  Then after the loop you need one last `adc $0, %[res]`.  Oh, that's what David already posted.

Comment: The first code block (with `shr` with a count of `$0`) appears to be buggy as well as inefficient.

Comment: The asm constraints on the version using `loop` are still unsafe: you tell the compiler that `"r"(x)` and ECX are a read-only inputs, but you destroy them.

Answer (score 5):

You are starting out with a really inefficient algorithm - if you use a better algorithm then you may not need to waste time with assembler. See [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org) and/or [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) for much more efficient methods.

Note also that newer x86 CPUs have a [POPCNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) instruction which does all of the above in one instruction (and you can [call it via an intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) too, so no need for asm).

And finally gcc has a builtin: [`__builtin_popcount`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), which again does all you need - it will use `POPCNT` on newer CPUs and equivalent asm on older CPUs.

Comment: My guess would be that this is a homework... So although you're providing probably the best solution, you're not answering the actual question "Now I need to translate the do-while loop into Assembly using 3-6 lines of code.".

Comment: @Vyktor: I fear you may be right, but the OP didn't mention anything about this being homework. I will leave this answer here though, as it may be useful to someone searching for a (non-homework) solution in the future.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer .But now I'm learning assembly an this is an exercise and I must resolve it with this algorithm. However I will have your answer in mind for a future ( when I know something more assembler :) ). Do you know how to resolve using my algorithm ?

Comment: @Antonio: OK - for future reference you should probably make constraints such as this clear in your question so that people don't waste time writing answers that you can not use. As for your assignment, use gcc -S to see what code the compiler generates for the C version and use that as a template for your inline asm.

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to create a popcount, I ended up using the 5's and 3's method from the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) @PaulR mentioned.  But if I wanted to do this with a loop, maybe something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int popcount2(int v) {
   int result = 0;
   int junk;

   asm (
        "shr $1, %[v]      \n\t"   // shift low bit into CF
        "jz done           \n"     // and skip the loop if that was the only set bit
     "start:               \n\t"
        "adc $0, %[result] \n\t"   // add CF (0 or 1) to result
        "shr $1, %[v]      \n\t"
        "jnz start         \n"     // leave the loop after shifting out the last bit
     "done:                \n\t"
        "adc $0, %[result] \n\t"   // and add that last bit

        : [result] "+r" (result), "=r" (junk)
        : [v] "1" (v)
        : "cc"
   );

   return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   for (int x=0; x < argc-1; x++)
   {
      int v = atoi(argv[x+1]);

      printf("%d %d\n", v, popcount2(v));
   }
}
```

`adc` is almost always more efficient than branching on CF.

`"=r" (junk)` is a dummy output operand that is in the same register as `v` (the `"1"` constraint).  We're using this to tell the compiler that the asm statement destroys the `v` input.  We could have used `[v] "+r"(v)` to get a read-write operand, but we don't want the C variable `v` to be updated.

Note that the loop trip-count for this implementation is the position of the highest set bit.  (`bsr`, or `32 - clz(v)`).  @rcgldr's implementation which clears the lowest set bit every iteration will typically be faster when the number of set bits is low but they're not all near the bottom of the integer.

Comment: I'm also still new to this stuff... Could you please explain your algorithm and `=r(junk)`?

Comment: 'junk' isn't some special keyword or anything.  It's just a variable (declared above).  The thing that makes it interesting is in the inputs where I declare that (v) should use the constraint "1".  This means it will share the same place as parameter #1.  So, on input the register will contain 'v'.  On output, it will contain the variable junk (meaning gcc won't mistakenly believe it can still find 'v' in that register).  Since gcc never needs the contents of junk, the register is immediately available for re-use.

Comment: As for the algorithm, well, the most interesting thing is that 'adc' means 'add with carry'.  If carry is not set, then 'adc $0, %[v]' does nothing.  Otherwise it adds 1.  This instruction is normally useful when adding REALLY big numbers (think: adding two 96 bit integers: 'add' the first 2 integers, then 'adc' then next two making sure to account for the overflow from the first add, etc).  This allows us to have fewer jump statements, which (typically, but not always) results in faster code.  I haven't actually timed it though, so yours could still be faster.

Comment: Thanks for explaining (I think you should move parts of the comments to your answer so it would provide more detailed, "teaching" explanation). I don't work with this, it's just a bit challenging stuff for me to do so that's why I'm interested. Anyway +1.

Comment: I wrote up a NASM version of this for [NASM: Count how many bits in a 32 Bit number are set to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363353) to compare it to the bithack.  I noticed `jz done` at the top is probably not worth doing: it's fine to always run the loop body exacly once for an input of 0, 1, 2, or 3.  For all other inputs, the jz is not-taken, so it's just a wasted uop that might mispredict.  Unless inputs of 0 or 1 are *very* common, it's not worth a jz to speed up that case at the slight expense of others.  (Or more than slight if it ever mispredicts.)

Answer (score 2):

> assembly using 3-6 lines of code.

This example uses a 4 instruction loop:

```
popcntx proc    near
        mov     ecx,[esp+4]             ;ecx = value to popcnt
        xor     eax,eax                 ;will be popcnt
        test    ecx,ecx                 ;br if ecx == 0
        jz      popc1
popc0:  lea     edx,[ecx-1]             ;edx = ecx-1
        inc     eax                     ;eax += 1
        and     ecx,edx                 ;ecx &= (ecx-1)
        jnz     short popc0
popc1:  ret
popcntx endp
```

This example uses a 3 instruction loop, but it would be slower than the 4 instruction loop version on most processors.

```
popcntx proc    near
        mov     eax,[esp+4]             ;eax = value to popcnt
        mov     ecx,32                  ;ecx = max # 1 bits
        test    eax,eax                 ;br if eax == 0
        jz      popc1
popc0:  lea     edx,[eax-1]             ;eax &= (eax-1)
        and     eax,edx
        loopnz  popc0
popc1:  neg     ecx
        lea     eax,[ecx+32]
        ret
popcntx endp
```

This is an alternative non-looping example:

```
popcntx proc    near
        mov     ecx,[esp+4]             ;ecx = value to popcnt
        mov     edx,ecx                 ;edx = ecx
        shr     edx,1                   ;mov upr 2 bit field bits to lwr
        and     edx,055555555h          ; and mask them
        sub     ecx,edx                 ;ecx = 2 bit field counts
                                        ; 0->0, 1->1, 2->1, 3->1
        mov     eax,ecx
        shr     ecx,02h                 ;mov upr 2 bit field counts to lwr
        and     eax,033333333h          ;eax = lwr 2 bit field counts
        and     ecx,033333333h          ;edx = upr 2 bit field counts
        add     ecx,eax                 ;ecx = 4 bit field counts
        mov     eax,ecx
        shr     eax,04h                 ;mov upr 4 bit field counts to lwr
        add     eax,ecx                 ;eax = 8 bit field counts
        and     eax,00f0f0f0fh          ; after the and
        imul    eax,eax,01010101h       ;eax bit 24->28 = bit count
        shr     eax,018h                ;eax bit 0->4 = bit count
        ret
popcntx endp
```

Comment: Looks like it would be simpler to `test eax,eax` / `jz .end` (after zeroing `ecx`) to skip the loop if eax=0, instead of always jumping to the loop-condition.  Same number of instructions, because you save the `mov ebx,eax` at the top of the loop.  Also, use `lea ebx, [rax-1]`  (or `[eax-1]` if this is 32-bit code) instead of `mov` / `dec`.  Or with BMI1, use `blsr ebx, eax` / `jnz`.  (Matt Godbolt mentioned this trick in his CppCon2017 talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4).

Comment: Also, use `edx` instead of `ebx`; edx is call-clobbered in typical calling conventions.

Comment: I found it with a search for `[x86] popcnt` looking for a dup target for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161950/check-number-of-bits-on-in-ax.    `lea edx, [eax-1]` is 3 bytes: opcode, ModR/M, disp8.  `LEA` only gets bulky if you use an index with no base to copy+shift (like `lea edx, [eax*4]`) because the only way to encode that is with a disp32=0.

Comment: The optimized version of this I suggested (with `lea`) is very likely faster than a shift loop for many inputs (especially relatively sparse inputs with the set bits not clustered at the bottom).  Especially on Intel where `adc` is 2 uops before Broadwell, and especially SnB-family where `and/jnz` macro-fuse into a compare-and-branch.  Unrolling might be helpful.  (You still need to branch, but the inner branch is `and/jz` to the end.)

Comment: With many bits set, an 8-bit LUT has better throughput, but of course can cache miss if not used frequently.  With SSSE3 but not `popcnt`, `pshufb` is reasonable.  Except on SlowShuffle CPUs like Merom, and most of the uarches with pshufb but not popcnt have slow pshufb...  But it's useful if you don't want to make a separate SSE4 version, just an SSSE3 version.  (Not sure about using it for scalar data, though.)

Comment: Oh right, derp yeah there are better bithack versions.  The mul / sub one is probably best. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: But this is potentially good if the expected count is very low.  It will suffer a branch miss, though.  The branchless bithack may be best depending on the surrounding code.

Comment: For the love of science, why would you use `loopnz`?  Are you tuning for AMD specifically?  [On Intel CPUs, that's much worse than `inc ecx` / ... / `jnz`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  Sure it's interesting, but only show that as the novelty 3-instruction trick version, not as the recommended / good version.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer for the non-looping version.  Feed that to a compiler with `unsigned`).

Comment: Avoiding `loopnz` is much faster on Intel (where `loopnz` is very slow), slightly slower on AMD Bulldozer-family (where `loopnz` is a single uop, but `and/jnz` don't fuse).  K10 has slow `loop` as well; it's only Bulldozer-family / Ryzen where `loopnz` is fast.  See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: `popcnt` is probably not a good choice of function name.  It's bound to lead to confusion when porting to NASM or something, because of the clash with the instruction name.  Further suggestion: link to the bithack question for the non-loop version, and mention that it's probably faster.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the `loopnz` version last.  It's more of a "here's how you can jump through a hoop and win at code-size".  It doesn't belong as the first code block.  Other than that, nice answer.

Comment: It's not always a good thing to make the most important / first part of your answer cover the weird special case of a specific question.  Sure, answer it somewhere, but answering the generic question well is also important.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I reordered the example, but left the non-looping version last so that the 4 and 3 instruction loop examples follow the quoted bit from the OP's question.