# Assembly x86: How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit long int

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, att

I'm a total newbie and I'm triyng to write the code to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer.

I wrote this but I get a lot of errors:

```
.586
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

; Windows libraries

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.DATA

data:   .LONG 0x0F0F0101
count:  .BYTE 0x00

.TEXT

_main:  NOP
        MOVB $0x00, %CL
        MOVL data, %EAX
comp:   CMPL $0x00, %EAX
        JE end
        SHRL %EAX
        ADCB $0x0, %CL
        JMP comp
end:    MOVB %CL, count
        RET
```

I have the following error:

```
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(20) : error A2034: must be in segment block
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(25) : error A2108: use of register assumed to ERROR
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(25) : error A2008: syntax error : .
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(26) : error A2108: use of register assumed to ERROR
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(26) : error A2008: syntax error : .
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(28) : error A2008: syntax error : .
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(29) : error A2108: use of register assumed to ERROR
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(30) : error A2008: syntax error : $0x00
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(31) : error A2008: syntax error : dato
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(32) : error A2108: use of register assumed to ERROR
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(32) : error A2008: syntax error : CMPL
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(34) : error A2008: syntax error : !%
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(35) : error A2008: syntax error : $0x0
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(37) : error A2108: use of register assumed to ERROR
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(37) : error A2008: syntax error : MOVB
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(38) : error A2088: END directive required at end of file
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(33) : error A2107: cannot have implicit far jump or call to near label
C:\Users\RaiN\Desktop\Test\test1.asm(36) : error A2107: cannot have implicit far jump or call to near label
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Cheat: write it in C, compile using -S switch, then review the generated assembler!

Comment: What assembler do you use?  Your output awefully looks like you try to use GNU assembler syntax with the Microsoft assembler. This can't work.

Comment: I use WinAsm Studio.For a test I need to use a Microsoft Assembler

Comment: @Yimin Rong Cheating would be using the POPCNT instruction. ;)

Comment: @icecreamsword: yeah, at least give yourself a challenge and slice the integer up into nibbles for a PSHUFB 4-bit LUT :)

Comment: This isn't exactly a new question.  [Last time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27053187/2189500) I wrote this, the requirement was to use inline asm.  But turning this to 'real' assembler shouldn't be too hard.  That said, the 5's and 3's method from the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) has been known to be faster than the popcnt instruction (depending on the specific cpu's implementation), and doesn't require asm.

Comment: Thank you David but I'm sorry, I'm at the beginning and I can't understand your suggestion.
What do you mean with inline asm and 5's and 3's method?
Thank you.

Comment: I have found another tool named SASM in which I can use also the AT&T syntax format and now the code works!

The problem is another... Do exist in Assembly an istruction like "System Pause"?
When I run the .exe files I have generated, I have not the ability to insert input and to watch the result.

Comment: @Rosikolo: Run your code in a debugger if you want to single-step the instructions.  There's no single asm instruction that makes your program wait for input.  You'd have to do that with a system call to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

New code is:

```
.text
.global main
main:
    movq %rsp, %rbp #for correct debugging
    # write your code here
.DATA
stringa:    .ASCIZ "Questa è la stringa di caratteri ASCII che usiamo come esempio"

lettera:     .BYTE 'e'
conteggio:   .BYTE 0x00

.TEXT
_main:        NOP
              MOV $0x00, %CL
              LEA stringa, %ESI
              MOV lettera, %AL
comp:         CMPB $0x00, (%ESI)
              JE fine
              CMP (%ESI), %AL
              JNE poi
              INC %CL
poi:          INC %ESI
              JMP comp
fine:         MOV %Cl, conteggio

              INT $0x27              
              RET
```

Comment: Since you posted this as an "Answer," does that mean the question is resolved?  Or is there still a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to calculate is called [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)
You can achieve this by using [Logical shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) and Bit Masking

Here is a simple program. Im assuming youre using x86 assembly.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include kernel32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib

.code
start:
    mov eax,1h             ;your number in eax 100 is sample here
    mov ecx,0h             ;is the counter register
    xor edx,edx            ;is done to make edx 0, you can also do mov edx,0
notDoneWithNumber:
    cmp eax,0
    je done
    mov edx,eax            ;edx is here a compare register, not nice, but it works
    shr eax,1              ;we push all the bits one place to the right, bits at position 1 will be "pushed out of the byteword"
    and edx,1h             ;make sure we only get, wether the last bit is set or not(thats called bitmaking) 
    cmp edx,0h
    jz notDoneWithNumber   ;if the found value is a zero we can skip the inc of the count register
    inc ecx
    jmp notDoneWithNumber
done:                      ;register ecx will now hold your hamming weight
end start
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but I have to improve the solution I have posted before...

Code could be built but I can't execute them on DOS. I don't understand how can I insert the I/O Function and the System Pause.

Comment: Oh I thought you would just need a working algorithm. When it comes to DOS im afraid I cant really help you, sorry.

Comment: `and edx, 1` already sets ZF based on the result.  You don't need `cmp edx, 0`.  You can simplify the branching, too, by using `shr eax / jnz notDone` as the jump at the bottom of the loop.  i.e. repeat the loop if the shift left any non-zero bits.  (This works best if you unconditionally `add ecx, edx` after masking it, instead of conditionally running an `inc`.  It's a lot more efficient to just add zero than to use a hard-to-predict branch to skip an `inc`.)

Comment: Of course, this whole one-bit-at-a-time algorithm is very slow compared to https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel, or especially SSSE3 pshufb (slice the input into 4-bit nibbles, and use those as parallel LUT indices).  Or of course the `popcnt` instruction is ideal for one integer at a time on CPUs that support it.

Comment: Yes you're right that algortihm is very slow. Im kind of new to assembly too, to be honest and i wanted to give an answer, thats easy to understand and clearly structured.