# Check number of bits on in ax

Tags: assembly, x86, bit

i need to find a way to check number of bits that is current on (1) in the ax register. i was thinking to use in shl or shr, but i do not know how exactly i suppose to use them. this is my code so far:

```
org 100h

mov ax, 0xffffh
;shr ax TO DO

int 16h
ret
```

i red in some place that the shift right function can move the bits to the right. so i might should use it by try to "push" the 16 bits to the right every time, and then check the LSB 1 or 0 flag? it sound to me as good idea.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Also note that `shr` puts the bit shifted out into the carry flag so you can easily count that using `adc`. There are more efficient algorithms of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `popcnt` instruction:

```
popcnt bx,ax
```

This sets `bx` to the number of bits set in ax. You need a somewhat recent CPU for this instruction to be available though.

Answer (score 1):

The shifted bit goes in the CF(carry flag) so one solution is that everytime after each shift you check that if CF=1 then increment a count variable that will tell the num of ON bits at the end.

Comment: Instead of a conditional jump and an increment, you could also simply use `adc` with an immediate of zero.

Comment: Yes that can also be an approach ^^