# How to check if more than one bit is set in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm writing an x86 assembly program and I want to check a register (it is not 0), to see if more than one bit is on.

Is there a simple way of doing it or should I just loop and shift until I see a 2nd set bit or get to the end?

---

I don't need the total number of set bits, that would be

- [Hamming weight ( number of 1 in a number) mixing C with assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050583/hamming-weight-number-of-1-in-a-number-mixing-c-with-assembly)
- [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Is there something faster than doing one of those and checking for `popcnt(x) > 1`?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050583/hamming-weight-number-of-1-in-a-number-mixing-c-with-assembly

Comment: Check out `popcnt`.

Comment: All register values with just a single bit set are powers of two. IIRC you can check `(reg - 1) & reg == 0` to find out whether the value is a power of two.

Comment: `(reg - 1) & reg` is available as `blsr` on modern CPUs (check the zero flag afterwards)

Answer (score 5):

As *almost* commented by [ecm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647538/how-to-check-if-more-than-one-bit-is-set-in-x86-assembly#comment128326246_72647538), one can check if a value is a power of two by checking

```
a) value != 0 &&
b) ((value - 1) & value) == 0
```

However, if one needs to check if a value has more than 1 bit, it is enough to test that

```
c) ((value - 1) & value) != 0

lea  ebx, [eax - 1]
test eax, ebx ;  // Z flag is cleared on EAX having 2 or more bits
```

That is: if a value is non-zero after some bit (that was originally set) has been cleared, it must have had more than 1 bit set.

BMI1 extension has a single instruction: clear least significant bit [blsr](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr), which also sets the ZF accordingly.

Comment: AMD CPUs (up to Zen3 at least) run `blsr` as 2 uops (https://uops.info/), so if you're going to branch on it, `lea`/`test` is actually *more* efficient there.  The `test` can fuse with a `jnz`, so it's 2 uops total.  (Same thing on Intel: `blsr` / `jnz` would be 2 uops total, same as `lea` / `test+jnz`.)  It does save code-size, and if you're going to `setnz` or `cmovnz` then it's break-even on AMD, and a win for `blsr` on Intel.

Comment: And apparently clang knows that, adding 1 is as good as subtracting 1 in that expression (gcc doesn't seem to know, though). https://godbolt.org/z/aKreaaars

Comment: @ErikEidt: Apparently the formulas didn't have enough parenthesis: the purpose was not to write `(x-1) & (x !=0)`, but `((x-1) & x) != 0`.