# x86: Count transitions from 1 to 0 in 32 bit number

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I like to count the number of 1 to 0 transition in a 32 bit number. I found that the number of transitions from 0 to 1 in reverse order using `shr`, but I don't get the required result. What should I do?

```
extern printf                   
SECTION .data                   
    msg:      db "The number of transitions are : %d",10,0  
    inta1:    dd 1234567   ; integer 1234567        
    num:      dd 4660  
SECTION .text                    

global main               
main:     
    mov eax, [num]    
    mov ecx,32    
    mov ebx,0    
.loop:  dec ecx  
    cmp ecx,0  
    jl .exit   
    shr eax,1  
    jc .loop  
    dec ecx  
    shr eax, 1  
    jnc .loop  
    inc ebx  
    jmp .loop  
.exit:  
    push ebx  
    push    dword msg          
    call    printf             
    add     esp, 8
```

**Output:**

> The number of transitions are : 2

whereas for 4660 (`00000000000000000001001000110100`) the number of 1 to 0 transitions are 4.

Comment: What value are you getting?

Comment: The number of transitions are : 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that your code looks for a `0` followed by a `1` and if it doesn't match, it starts over again.  So if it sees `00` it starts over looking for another `0` and if the next bit is `1` it starts over.  So you miss transitions when they are preceeded by an even number of `0`s

Note also you say you want 1-to-0 transitions, but you're looking for 0-to-1 transitions, *BUT* you are looking right to left (lsb to msb) so that may be correct, depending on which bit order you want.

The obvious solution is to change the `jnc .loop` to not start over, but only go back to the immediately preceeding `dec ecx`, though you also need a `cmp ecx,0; jl .exit` there.

Note also you could get rid of the need of `ecx` and counting the number of bits by using the `Z` flag which is set by the `shr` instruction when the result (in `eax`) is all 0 bits.

Taken together, that gives you something like:

```
.loop1: shr eax, 1
        jc .loop1
.loop2: jz .exit
        shr eax, 1
        jnc .loop2
        inc ebx
        jmp .loop1
```

Comment: The last `jmp .loop` should be `jmp .loop1` (+1 anyway).

Comment: You could maybe structure the loop with a `jnz` at the bottom, and enter it with a `test eax,eax / jmp loop_entry_point`.  Then you'd have one less instruction in the loop (no unconditional branch).  Also note that you can add `CF` to `ebx` with `adc ebx, 0`.  Or `setc dl` / `add bl, dl`.  Either way, you can avoid a conditional branch on the bit shifted out, since that will probably not predict well.

Answer (score 4):

Trivia: I thought about this some month ago while trying to implement an aspect of a bitmap based memory manager.

The most efficient solution I found is the following (I adapted it to your sample code):

```
global main               
main:     
    mov eax, [num]    
    ; --- here starts the relevant code ---
    mov ebx, eax         
    shl ebx, 1
    not eax
    and ebx, eax
    popcnt ebx, ebx     ; --- count the changed bits ---
    ; --- continue with your exit routine
.exit:  
    push ebx  
    push    dword msg          
    call    printf             
    add     esp, 8
```

Notice that the calculation is achieved without loops. It is pure bit-fiddling with the set bits being counted at last by the `POPCNT` instruction giving the desired result.

As an example - applied to the given value of 4660 this algorithm functions like this:

```
00000000000000000001001000110100 --- MOV EBX, EAX

00000000000000000010010001101000 --- SHL EBX, 1
11111111111111111110110111001011 --- NOT EAX
00000000000000000010010001001000 --- AND EBX, EAX => 'and' the last two lines
=> POPCNT (count the bits of the last line) to get the result of 1 to 0 transitions.
```

Comment: @SaumyaSahay, if you have to choose between the book and `popcnt`, you should choose `popcnt` (books get outdated).

Comment: @Saumya Sahay: Yes, it could be done without `POPCNT` if you'd manually implement a routine to count the bits in a `DWORD`. This has been done and is very tiresome, but luckily nearly all current processors do support [POPCNT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPCNT.html) for many years. It was introduced [by AMD with `Barcelona architecture` (SSE4a) in 2007 and by Intel with `Nehalem architecture` in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4.2#POPCNT_and_LZCNT). IMHO this may be considered a decent age for a processor feature.