# Assembly language program to count number of 1's in binary number

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, hammingweight

Can someone please help I stuck since few day on this problem. I want to count numbers of 1's in binary value of 2 decimal/hexa. But I am getting incorrect results. Here a code below:

```
.386  //32-bit processor
.model small, stdcall  
ExitProcess PROTO, deExitCode:DWORD  
.data  
var1 dw 2  
.code  
main PROC  
    LEA ESI,var1  
    MOV EBX, 4 //SIZE OF ARRAY AS 2 binary will be 0010  
    MOV ECX,0  
 L1:CMP EBX,0  
    JE L3  
    MOV EAX,[ESI]  
    CMP EAX,0  
    JE L2  
    INC ECX  
 L2:DEC EBX  
    ADD SI,2  
    JMP L1  
 L3: INVOKE ExitProcess,0  
main ENDP  
END main
```

Comment: [NASM: Count how many bits in a 32 Bit number are set to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2931497) shows some efficient loops for doing this on 32 bits at a time.  Use a `movzx` load to widen a 16 bit value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your weird terminology *to count numbers of 1's in binary value*, you want to count how many bits is set to 1 in a 16bit memory variable `var1`. A straightforward solution is to load the variable to a register (`MOVZX EAX,[var1]`) and then 16 times shift the lowest bit to CF (`SHR EAX,1`) and add the CF to a counter register (`ADC ECX,0`) each time.

However, your code seems to count how many of four words in memory has a nonzero value. There are some bugs in it:

- *SIZE OF ARRAY* which you have statically defined as `var1` is not 4. It would have to be defined as `var1 DW 2,3,4,5 ; Array of four words.`
- `MOV EAX,[ESI]` correctly loads `AX` from `var1` but it also loads
  whatever garbage follows `var1` to upper 16 bits of `EAX`.
- `ADD SI,2` should
  be `ADD ESI,2`.

Comment: thanks for your solution